# utilização de funções para ler e imprimir numeros

Tags: c, funções

Quero utilizar duas funções, cada uma para ler um número, e uma outra função para imprimir esses números na tela. Não quero declarar variáveis globais, quero passar esses valores como parâmetros de escopo local.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>


int ler_primeiro(int n1);  
int ler_segundo(int n2);

int mostrar();


int main()

{
    
    mostrar();
    
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

int ler_primeiro(int n1)

{

    int numero1;
    
    printf("Informe o primeiro numero: ");
    scanf("\n%d", &numero1);
    
    return numero1;
}

int ler_segundo(int n2)

{

    int numero2;
    
    printf("Informe o segundo numero: ");
    scanf("\n%d", &numero2);
    
    return numero2;
}

int mostrar()

{

    int n1, n2;
    
    ler_primeiro(n1);
    ler_segundo(n2);
    printf("\nprimeiro numero: %d, segundo numero: %d", n1, n2);
}
```

Ao realizar o debug verifiquei que o comando scanf das funções "ler_primeiro e "ler_segundo" estão corretos, consigo ler os valores das variáveis de forma correta, porém os printfs chamados na função "mostrar" retorna os valores 0 e 46, não importando qual valor digitado na função scanf. Não sei onde estou errando.

Comment: Dentro das funções ler_ vc não usa os parâmetros  `n1` e `n2` para nada. Em vez disso, vc usa outra variável e retorna ela. Então ou deveria pegar o retorno da função (assim: https://ideone.com/1aJGLy), ou as funções recebem um ponteiro (assim: https://ideone.com/JcmM43). Se bem que as duas funções fazem praticamente a mesma coisa, e a função `mostrar` faz mais do que apenas mostrar (ela também chama as funções que lêem), então poderia ser assim: https://ideone.com/S7BEKF

Comment: @hkotsubo Primeiro obrigado por ter corrigido a formatação do código, não estou familiarizado com essa plataforma ainda, preciso aprender a editar melhor minhas perguntas. Em relação ao código, eu tenho dúvidas sobre parâmetros, em alguma situação é necessário utilizar eles para retornar valores para outras funções? E em relação a variável n utilizada como ponteiro, na função "mostrar" os ponteiros  das funções "ler" foram chamadas utilizando o "&", pq foi necessária a utilização desse caractere? Sei que são perguntas bobas, mas esses assuntos são um pouco complexos pra mim.

Comment: Se `x` é uma variável, `&x` é o endereço dela (ou um ponteiro pra `x`). Algumas funções precisam do endereço (como `scanf`). Quanto ao resto, uma função pode retornar um valor, ou receber um ponteiro e modificá-lo, quando usar um ou outro depende de váriosf fatores. Mas eu sugiro primeiro estudar o básico de funções (e depois ponteiros). Não gosto de sugerir material pq vai muito do gosto (só fica o alerta para youtubers e blogueiros, tem muita coisa ruim por aí), mas enfim, aqui não tem espaço pra explicar tudo.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Está errado porque, apesar de retornar o valor lido nas funcões `ler_xx()` não está usando o valor de retorno.
E não há razão para a função que lê um valor receber um argumento inteiro. Ela apenas retorna o que leu. Algo assim estaria bem

```
int ler_primeiro()
{
    int numero1;
    printf("Informe o primeiro numero: ");
    scanf("\n%d", &numero1);
    return numero1;
}
```

para o propósito. E usaria assim

```
    int n1 = ler_primeiro();
```

Mas essa não é a idéia de escrever uma função. Veja que usou até `numero1` e `numero2` como nome **dentro** das duas funções. Se fosse ler 2.000 nomes você então usaria 2.000 funções? E a mensagem que sai na tela fica **DENTRO** da função? Não pode sequer trocar a mensagem sem mudar a função para o programa todo? Toda a idéia de usar uma função é poder reusar código.

Considere essa:

```
int ler(const char* prompt)
{
    int n   = 0;
    int res = 0;
    if (prompt != NULL) printf("%s", prompt);
    do {
         res = scanf("%d",&n);
    } while (res != 1);
    return n;
}
```

Que usa assim:

```
    int n1 = ler("Informe o primeiro numero: ");
    int n2 = ler("Informe o segundo numero: ");
    int outro = ler(NULL);
```

Uma única função, qualquer prompt, mesmo nenhum. E o valor é usado direto na declaração. Sem chance de se perder.

#### `mostra()`

```
int mostrar()
{
    int n1 = ler_primeiro();
    int n2 = ler_segundo();
    printf("\nprimeiro numero: %d,"
        "segundo numero: %d",
        n1, n2);
}
```

Assim funcionaria, mas também está errado: toda vez que vai mostrar os números eles são lidos de novo? Qual o sentido de uma função assim? E o texto é fixo também? Porque não pode mostrar duas vezes? ou uma? ou nenhuma e apenas gravar em um arquivo os 2.000 números lidos, por exemplo?

Considere:

```
int mostrar(int n,const char* mensagem)
{
    if (mensagem != NULL) printf("%s", mensagem);
    printf(" %d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

E use assim:

```
    mostrar(n1, "primeiro numero: ");
    mostrar(n2, "segundo numero: ");
```

- não use `system()` e muito menos `system("pause")` em seus programas. Todo mundo que rodar seu programa vai ter que teclar um ENTER depois de rodar porque o programa vai ficar parado esperando. É muito chato. E o que dizer de um script que roda o programa duas vezes? Ou um programa de execução automática que vai rodar todos os programas de sua turma? Alguém vai ficar lá pra teclar ENTER? Se quer rodar o programa dentro de um IDE --- sim, IDE é masculino --- e ele não para aprenda como dizer para ele não fechar a janela. Se não tem jeito dele fazer isso apenas use outro IDE. Tem muitos bons ambientes desses. E ode não usar nenhum. Programas tipo console devem rodar no terminal afinal.

> Ao realizar o debug verifiquei que o comando scanf das funções "ler_primeiro e "ler_segundo" estão corretos, consigo ler os valores das variáveis de forma correta, porém os printfs chamados na função "mostrar" retorna os valores 0 e 46. Poderiam dizer onde estou errando, por favor.

Acho que já sabe porque os valores errados foram mostrados. Quanto a `scanf()` não é o debugger que vai dizer que leu de forma correta. Leia o manual: a função retorna um `int` e esse `int` vai te dizer se leu algo ou não. Seu programa não vai rodar no "debugger" a vida toda.

#### O código do exemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ler(const char*);
int mostrar(int,const char*);

int main(void)
{
    int n1 = ler("Informe o primeiro numero: ");
    int n2 = ler("Informe o segundo numero: ");
    mostrar(n1, "primeiro numero: ");
    mostrar(n2, "segundo numero: ");
    return 0;
}

int ler(const char* prompt)
{
    int n   = 0;
    int res = 0;
    if (prompt != NULL) printf("%s", prompt);
    do {
         res = scanf("%d",&n);
    } while (res != 1);
    return n;
}

int mostrar(int n,const char* mensagem)
{
    if (mensagem != NULL) printf("%s", mensagem);
    printf(" %d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

que mostra

```
Informe o primeiro numero: 42
Informe o segundo numero: 17
primeiro numero:  42
segundo numero:  17
```

Comment: Não imaginava que algo simples como ler dois números utilizando funções puxaria tantos conceitos de C, obrigado pelos esclarecimentos, vou continuar trabalhando no código me baseando nas suas considerações. Obrigado.

Comment: Entendeu como é mais flexível escrever assim, e quase inútil escrever as funções daquele modo inicial? Isso se aplica a praticamente qualquer linguagem. Veja o exemplo de `mostra` que sempre chamava 2 funções para ler 2 números com mensagens fixas e não podia apenas mostrar. :)

Comment: suas sugestões, juntas com a do "hkotsubo" me deram um norte, obrigado. Postei um novo código acima, só não sei se ele faz mais sentido que o anterior rs.

Comment: Pensei em discutir a pergunta mas eu já tinha feito isso. Pensei em acrescentar algum código mas eu já tinha feito isso. Pensei em acrescentar a saída do exemplo e alguma argumentação mas eu já tinha feito isso. Vou estudar mais.

Comment: Então minha resposta é inútil. apesar de discutir o uso de funções em C e mostrando um exemplo do uso clássico, com código e resultando inseridos, sem remeter usuários para sites externos de compiladores online.  Se eu estivesse começando a programar em C acho que me benefiiciaria de ler esse tópico, mas imagino que não estaria eu a altura do que o SO espera de um leitor também.